# Does bitmap of an image remains constant throughout the lifecycle of the android application?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

Okay so this might be a very silly question to ask.
Does a bitmap of an image remains constant traversing through different activities in the android.

Well my issue is :
I have an activity with image view having a default image.
I am previewing another image picked from the gallery if the user wants it.

So now then i move on to the next activity displaying the image user picked from the gallery.
Now if the user hasn't picked any image i want to show another default image.

Please note not the 1st default image in 2nd activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a bitmap remains in the `drawables` folder, then you can access it from every `Activity` and it will remain "constant" so to say (if that's what you meant). If you're using the bitmap in the code (to set it as the background of the `ImageView`), then this can be changed - othwerise if in drawables - it's just usable, you can manipulate it, but you will never change its basic status (in the folder).

Comment: thnx buddy for ur answer